# get data from a text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I'm trying to extract data from a text file with the following structure:

```
Employee: John C.
  2013-01-01  10  $123
  2013-01-02  12  $120
  2013-01-03  8  $150
Employee: Michael G.
  2013-01-01  5  $13
  2013-01-05  11  $20
  2013-01-10  2  $155
```

As you can see, the pattern is a table header containing the Employee name and then table content containing all of its transactions, then the pattern repeats.

To extract transactions I do this:

```
awk '/^  [A-Z]/{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3}'
```

This gives this result:

```
  2013-01-01  10  $123
  2013-01-02  12  $120
  2013-01-03  8   $150
  2013-01-01  5   $13
  2013-01-05  11  $20
  2013-01-10  2   $155
```

How can I create a two pass extraction that returns this:

```
  2013-01-01  10  $123  John C.
  2013-01-02  12  $120  John C.
  2013-01-03  8   $150  John C.
  2013-01-01  5   $13   Michael G.
  2013-01-05  11  $20   Michael G.
  2013-01-10  2   $155  Michael G.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk -F":" '/^Employee/{a=$NF;next}{print $0,a}' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
Employee: John C.
  2013-01-01  10  $123
  2013-01-02  12  $120
  2013-01-03  8  $150
Employee: Michael G.
  2013-01-01  5  $13
  2013-01-05  11  $20
  2013-01-10  2  $155
$ awk -F":" '/^Employee/{a=$NF;next}{print $0,a}' file
  2013-01-01  10  $123  John C.
  2013-01-02  12  $120  John C.
  2013-01-03  8  $150  John C.
  2013-01-01  5  $13  Michael G.
  2013-01-05  11  $20  Michael G.
  2013-01-10  2  $155  Michael G.
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for GNU sed:

```
sed '/:/{s/[^:]\+://;H;x;s/.*\n//;d};G;s/\n//' file
```